# Something like $ or @@ variable, but unique for each user session. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have array of objects. I can't store it in DB for performance reason. I tried store array in Global ($var) and Class (@@var) variables (in controller), but it was the same array for all users. It should be unique for each user session and in each session it should be able to be modified quickly.

I understand that the session[] - is not the best solution. What is the best way?

I'm doing something like this `$lines_rules << Processing::rule_creator(...)` in every time, when run action in controller.

$lines_rules - it is my array of objects.

Why DB is not right for store $lines_rules? In $lines_rules I store objects with lambda function. When user press button I need call every lambda function with user input and keep result. Then I load new objects into $lines_rules. Thus every request change $lines_rules. I think work with memory is the better way for perfomance.

**UPDATE**

I use `$global_hash [ session[:session_id] ]` and this technique for resource saving:

```
def dead_sessions_killer
  ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.where(["updated_at < ?", 30.minutes.ago]).each do |session|
    $global_hash.delete_if {|key, value| key == session.session_id }
    session.delete
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you clarify what DBs were inadequate and in what way? (e.g. Inserts and selects creating locking issues or just the roundtrip time to the other process was too long?)

Comment: Are you trying to have a shared state for an array of objects for all requests in one variable that is not reloaded per request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a global, but a global hash, keyed by the user's session id.

Store whatever you want in there, although with proper caching, hard to say if this is a great idea.

Comment: It is interesting idea. But I feel worried about memory expense

Comment: @x403 As well you should, but other than a database, memory, or a file, where else can you put it?

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the array as a class variable (only 1 @ sign), and provide an accessor method.

That is:

```
class Foo

  @some_array

  def some_array
    @some_array
  end

end
```

From other classes, this lets you call `foo_instance.some_array`, which keeps the array specific to the user, but allows public access from any class.

Comment: When I do it in Controller - no way, because no instance. When I do it in separate class - the same problem. 
In controller I should again do somethings like that: @@var = Foo.new or $var = Foo.new

Answer (score 0):

You could store the user session in memory with memcache. That would be convenient and fast.

http://awesomerails.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/rails-3-memcached-session-store/

Comment: Not so simple like a global variable